# "Permission denied to shadow native property" using location.replace to redirect in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm being bugged by this issue which I'm facing with `location.replace`. I need to simulate an HTTP redirect (I don't want my users to get stuck in a never-ending back button fiasco for this particular piece of functionality I'm implementing) so I'm using `location.replace` instead of `location.href` to redirect. However, I constantly end up on getting the below error message in my console on `Firefox 12.0`.

`Permission denied to shadow native property`

Below is my code (I'm masking off my server details from the request URL while adding the code here)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".workout_sel_month").click(function() {
       month_number = $(this).attr('id').replace(/month/g,"");
       weekwise_workout_url = "http://www.example.com/viewrecord/getscheduleformonth";
       location.replace = weekwise_workout_url + "&month_number=" + month_number;
    });

});
```

Please note that if I use `location.href` instead it works like a charm. What may be the cause of this? . If this is a duplicate post (I did some basic search and found some posts but none of them particularly suited my case), my sincerest apologies and in that case please link me up with the appropriate question here. :)

Comment: Btw. this is an interesting find. I planned to override `history.pushState` from a Firefox plugin. Now I wonder if this is still possible... I hope so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`location.replace` is a **function**. By assigning a value to the property you are trying to override it (which you are not allowed to).

`location.href` on the other hand just contains a string which you are allowed to change.

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).

---

To clarify a bit more:

The fact alone that `location.replace` is a function does not imply that this property is immutable, but it makes the decision to do so understandable:
Functions are supposed to be called, they should not be overridden. I assume that's why this property is immutable as opposed to others. Properties containing strings, numbers, etc. are more likely meant to be changed.

But any property could be marked as immutable, no matter its value.

Comment: Oh No! How did I miss this? Thanks a zillion :) Will green check this after this 7 mins cause it is locked now.

Answer (score 2):

I'ts a function and not a value.
What browser is assuming right now is that you wish to override a native property which is a function with your own function. That throws the error.
The right syntax is

location.replace("url");

Your code would need to become

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".workout_sel_month").click(function() {
       month_number = $(this).attr('id').replace(/month/g,"");
       weekwise_workout_url = "http://www.example.com/viewrecord/getscheduleformonth";
       location.replace(weekwise_workout_url + "&month_number=" + month_number);
    });

});
```

Comment: "*I'ts a function and not a property."* is not correct. Of course it's a property, but its value is a function.

Comment: It is host (Firefox) that disallows you to override, not JavaScript itself.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, it is nitpick, but keep in mind that people with various levels of JavaScript knowledge might read your answer. Being precise avoids confusion. Btw, functions are values too ;) *duck and run*

Comment: *throws empty sodacan at @FelixKling 's head* Unfortunately you're right... I just like keping things simple and readable for the more novice users ;-) But because you're right i've edited my answer to represent the truth a bit more.
Now you have a difficult point. How to call a non function property then, because a variable can also be a function... so what is the exclusive name for a property/variable/value that is not a function...

Comment: *ouch, headshot* ... I don't know if there is any. Maybe you could say that properties holding functions are "methods" (in the sense of OOP), but that does not mean anything regarding their mutability.

Comment: This throws exactly the same error in Firefox 14.0.1 as the OP's error... Still a no go sorry to say.